# Keep printing values after refresh in PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and I created a simple game where you get points always when you roll two dice at the same time but lose when the numbers on the dice that were rolled are identical (e.g. two twos, two threes...)

I've got the code but would like to keep printing the score (and possibly calculating total score) after refreshing the page until the player loses by rolling two identical numbers.

I've got this so far:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Rolling Dice</title> 

</head> <body> <h1>Press "F5" to roll your dice</h1> 

<? $roll = rand(1,6); 
print "You rolled a $roll"; 
print "<br>"; 

if ($roll == 1){   
print "<img src = dice1.png>";
 }else if ($roll == 2){  
print "<img src = dice2.png>";
   } else if ($roll == 3){
print "<img src = dice3.png>";
 } else if ($roll == 4){   
print "<img src = dice4.png>";
  }else if ($roll == 5){  
print "<img src = dice5.png>";
 } else if ($roll == 6){  
print "<img src = dice6.png>";
   } else {   print "<img src = dice1.png>";   
} //end if"<img src = dice1.png>"};

$roll2 = rand(1,6); 
print "<br>"; 
print "You rolled a $roll2"; 
print "<br>"; 

if ($roll2 == 1){   
print "<img src = dice1.png>";
 }else if ($roll2 == 2){  
print "<img src = dice2.png>";
   } else if ($roll2 == 3){
print "<img src = dice3.png>";
 } else if ($roll2 == 4){   
print "<img src = dice4.png>";
  }else if ($roll2 == 5){  
print "<img src = dice5.png>";
 } else if ($roll2 == 6){  
print "<img src = dice6.png>";
   } else {   print "<img src = dice1.png>";   
} //end if"<img src = dice1.png>"};

$result = ($roll+$roll2);

if ($roll == $roll2){
print "<br>"; 
print "You lost!"; 
print "<br>"; 
}
else

{

echo "<br>"; 
echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=2><thead><tr><td>Score</td></tr></thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
 echo "<tr><td>$result</td></tr>";
echo "You got $result";
echo "</tbody></table>";
print "<br>";

} 

print "<br>"; 

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll Again" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use session,
try this one:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Rolling Dice</title>

    </head> <body> <h1>Press "F5" to roll your dice</h1>

        <?php
        session_start();
        $roll = rand(1, 6);
        print "You rolled a $roll";
        print "<br>";

        if ($roll == 1) {
            print "<img src = dice1.png>";
        } else if ($roll == 2) {
            print "<img src = dice2.png>";
        } else if ($roll == 3) {
            print "<img src = dice3.png>";
        } else if ($roll == 4) {
            print "<img src = dice4.png>";
        } else if ($roll == 5) {
            print "<img src = dice5.png>";
        } else if ($roll == 6) {
            print "<img src = dice6.png>";
        } else {
            print "<img src = dice1.png>";
        } //end if"<img src = dice1.png>"};

        $roll2 = rand(1, 6);
        print "<br>";
        print "You rolled a $roll2";
        print "<br>";

        if ($roll2 == 1) {
            print "<img src = dice1.png>";
        } else if ($roll2 == 2) {
            print "<img src = dice2.png>";
        } else if ($roll2 == 3) {
            print "<img src = dice3.png>";
        } else if ($roll2 == 4) {
            print "<img src = dice4.png>";
        } else if ($roll2 == 5) {
            print "<img src = dice5.png>";
        } else if ($roll2 == 6) {
            print "<img src = dice6.png>";
        } else {
            print "<img src = dice1.png>";
        } //end if"<img src = dice1.png>"};

        $result = ($roll + $roll2);
        if ($roll == $roll2) {
            print "<br>";
            print "You lost!";
            print "<br>";
            if (isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
                session_destroy();
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
                $_SESSION['result'] = $_SESSION['result'] + $result;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['result'] = $result;
            }
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=2><thead><tr><td>Score</td></tr></thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr><td>" . $_SESSION['result'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "You got $result";
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            print "<br>";
        }

        print "<br>";
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Roll Again" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to code something like that but didn't know how to put it together. Excellent ! :)